# What are this connectors on Power Supply?

Tags: power-supply, cable, connector, atx

Pictures

Connectors

[image]

PSU Details

[image]

Comment: Is that one cable or two? Are they connected to the PSU or not?

Comment: The thick single wire is probably a grounding lug, many older server PSU's have these to ensure that everything is grounded properly.  Not sure about the other one though, I don't recognize the connector type at all.

Comment: These are two separate cables coming out of the PSU.

Comment: Also what size are they? Top looks like it would fit a molex fan header; bottom one might be an earth lead to connect to a case?

Comment: +1 to fan connector, small black headed one to the left and fork like earthing cable to the right.

Comment: Yes I think the right one is earth, the left one is exactly the size and shape of front panel connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom cord is black and, according to the picture of the power supply, it is the ground (or Earth) wire, marked as GND in the power supply picture.  The top one looks purple in your picture, and according to the picture of the power supply, that line is +5VSB.  VSB on a power supply is voltage standby, so even when the power supply is in a low power mode (like "sleep" or "hibernate"), that line still has 5V running through it.

EDIT: The primary use of the +5VSB line is to retain memory data during standby/sleep/hibernate mode. It can also be used to power the motherboard circuitry that does a "soft power on" (when you press the power button).  If it isn't plugged in, then the memory is being retained during sleep mode via a cache on the hard drive, and the soft power on is using full voltage, which doesn't hurt anything (as far as I know).